# Writing monomial symmetric functions in terms of population moments about the mean

Tags: expected-value, moments, function, symmetry

Following Sukhatme (1954, pp.35 - 36) for a univariate case, I encountered the following population monomial 'symmetric' functions for a bivariate case: $\sum_{i=1}^{N}(X_i^2Y_i^2)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j=1}^{N}(X_i^2Y_j^2)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j=1}^{N}(X_i^2Y_iY_j)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j\neq k=1}^{N}(X_i^2Y_jY_k)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j=1}^{N}(X_iX_jY_j^2)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j\neq k=1}^{N}(X_iX_jY_k^2)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j=1}^{N}(X_iX_jY_iY_j)$ $;$ $\sum_{i\neq j\neq k=1}^{N}(X_iX_jY_iY_k)$ and $\sum_{i\neq j\neq k\neq l=1}^{N}(X_iX_jY_kY_l)$$.$ ***So now my question is-*** Does any table exist that can enable one to express these populations functions above in terms of the population moments about the mean. I was able to write that of the univariate case with the help of the table cited in Cornish and Fisher (1938). Do we have a bivariate version of this table.